# TableLayoutPanel Controls - Lock Column from Horizontal Scroll?

Tags: .net, winforms, scroll, tablelayoutpanel

I'm using a TableLayoutPanel in a Windows Forms application to organize a set of controls in a grid-like fashion.  I'd like to lock the TableLayoutPanel's first controls column so that it remains fixed when the user applies the horizontal scrollbar.  Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the TableLayoutPanel in the designer and select "Edit Rows and Columns...".  Then set the first column to use an absolute width instead of a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

I think for what you're wanting to do, you need to create a two column TableLayoutPanel, then within each column create an additional TableLayoutPanel.  On the side you want to allow scrolling, set AllowScroll = true for its sub-TableLayoutPanel, and on the side you want not to scroll, set AllowScroll = false for its sub-TableLayoutPanel.